# Batch command to delete folders with specific name and age

Tags: windows, batch-file, command, directory, delete-file

I already have a script (see below) to recursively delete files with a specific extensions and older than x number of days.

I'm looking for the command to recursively delete empty folders where the name begins with `{` and ends with `}` and is older than x number of days. Any ideas?

```
set deletepath="C:\test"
set days=10

for %G in (.log, .dat, .sts, .mdn, .req, .err,  .edi, .xml.filename, .xml) do FORFILES /P %deletepath% /S /M *%G /D -%days% /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  Test it on sample folders first.

```
FORFILES /P %deletepath% /S /M "{*}" /D -%days% /C "cmd /c if @isdir==TRUE rd @path 2>nul"
```

It will only remove the folder if it is empty - the `2>nul` removes harmless error messages when there are files inside the folder.